# What lawful interception standards are used outside Europe?

Tags: legal, international

In Europe European Telecommunications Standards Institute (ETSI) define the standard requirements to handle a lawful interception.

It's define all from the terminology and definition to the technical encoding of the payload that will be intercepted and given to the authority.

What standards are used (if there is) in USA and in other major world players like China, Japan, UK, Brazil, Canada, India, Russia, Australia ?

Comment: Super old, but what exactly are you asking? If I read this correctly, in the US, the wire tap laws we have apply to data interception.

Comment: In Europe we have some standard regulation which goal is to regulate and standardize how the lawful interception network need to be deployed in every state of the Europe. is there a 'regulation' like that to uniform how lawful interception system need to be deployed ?

Comment: As a side note, if you **need** to know, don't expect a standard to tell you everything. I doubt standard are followed all the time and assuming the worst case scenario is very important when talking about security (weakest link, bla bla). Would you mind explaining why you mind about this? Just curiosity?

Comment: In Italy, our provider implement Lawful Interception following the ETSI specification, so every provider have a common way to do LI. For my employer I'm get involved in the design of a software solution, with a functional requirement of compatibility with ETSI standard. So after reading some of that specification the curiosity about non-EU get in me. :)

Answer (score 2):

CALEA in the US: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALEA

Comment: Hi @bab, my other comment applies here too :)

Comment: What comment do you mean ?